# Loading a DER-encoded RSA key using M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto

The method `M2Crypto.RSA.RSA().save_key_der()` can be used to save a key in the DER format. However, I do not see a corresponding method `M2Crypto.RSA.load_key_der()` as I would expect.

Is there a way to load a DER-encoded RSA key using M2Crypto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PEM format is base64-encoded DER data with some additional header and footer lines. You can just read DER as binary, transform it to PEM and pass that to `RSA.load_key_string`:

```
import base64
from M2Crypto import RSA

TEMPLATE = """
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
%s
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
raw = open('key.der', 'rb').read()
data = TEMPLATE % base64.encodestring(raw).rstrip()
key = RSA.load_key_string(data)
print key
```

Output:

```
<M2Crypto.RSA.RSA instance at 0x10eb710>
```

Comment: For posterity, Python also has "ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert()" and "ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert()" to do exactly this.

Comment: @Dustin: but DER_cert_to_PEM_cert will print "CERTIFICATE" instead of "RSA PRIVATE KEY", which will confuse M2Crypto.

Comment: @DominiqueEav Thanks for sharing. I don't use it, so I didn't know this.