# Cannot figure out how to publish public key generated on iPhone

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, security, rsa

I am using the `commoncrypto` library on the iPhone to create a pair of RSA keys and I am trying to send the public key to a server (Python) so that I can use it to verify a signature sent from the phone.

I'm using the exact code from the CommonCrypto example using the method `getPublicKeyBits()` which looks like this:

`- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBits {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData* publicKeyBits = nil;
    NSData* publicTag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier)];
    CFDataRef cfresult = NULL;

```
NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

// Get the key bits.
sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef*)&cfresult); 


if (sanityCheck != noErr)
{
    publicKeyBits = nil;
}
else 
{
    publicKeyBits = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)cfresult;
}

return publicKeyBits;
```

}`

The problem is that I don't know how, exactly, the key is being stored or how to pass it. I am using the `getPublicKeyBits()` to get it in a `NSData` structure, and I've imported a library to encode it in `base64`.  I'm getting a key (SHA1, I'd like to move to SHA256, but that's secondary to getting this working) and the `base64` version looks like other keys I've found here and in other people solving RSA problems.

I've been trying to use the `M2Crypto` library in Python and when I try to verify I'm getting the error `"RSA Error: No Start Line"`. Here's the code I'm using to receive the public key:

```
pubKey = request.form['publickey']

uid = uuid4().hex
while not unique(uid, User):
    uid = uuid.uuid4().hex
user = User(uid, email, secret, pubKey)
```

And the code I'm using to check the signature:

```
def validate(sessionKey, sig, pem):
    bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(pem.encode('ascii'))
    rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
    pubkey = EVP.PKey()
    pubkey.assign_rsa(rsa)

    pubkey.reset_context(md='sha1')
    pubkey.verify_init()
    pubkey.verify_update(sessionKey)

    return pubkey.verify_final(sig)
```

I'm really stumped as to what I'm doing wrong but I feel like I'm getting close. If my whole method is not the way you'd do it, I'd love to hear any other way to generate RSA keys on the phone, publish the public key to a server, and then verify a signature from the phone on that server.

Thanks!

Comment: could you post also your iOS code that you use for creating the public key data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *getPublicKeyBits* method from SecKeyWrapper in the Apple CryptoExercise code

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_h.html

This will get you the DER encoded binary data. Then use the following method to load it into M2Crypto in Python: (Basically, just base64 it and invoke one method.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5765576/584616

I have an ARC enabled version of this *getPublicKeyBits* method, but I haven't gotten around to posting it yet.

**Update** - on re-reading your question, the answer is actually here:

[How to find out the modulus and exponent of RSA Public Key on iPhone/Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840005/how-to-find-out-the-modulus-and-exponent-of-rsa-public-key-on-iphone-objective-c)

You can use this to get the modulus and exponent as NSData, which you should be able to easily convert into base64 or your representation of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying implementation of M2Crypto is OpenSSL. OpenSSL will not import your pure public key as you exported it but only if it is "embedded" in a possibly self-signed certificate. Check out how to create a self-signed certificate with Common Crypto or Security framework, embed your public key and sign it with your private key, extract its data and send it to your server: it should work.

See also [openssl_pkey_get_public not open public key, "no start line" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617293/openssl-pkey-get-public-not-open-public-key-no-start-line-error) (the second answer)

Comment: What do you mean "extract its data"?

Comment: The same thing as you used for your private key: once you have the certificate in the memory, copy the binary data into NSData and send the byte stream to the server.